# How to print a String in specific line in java.io.PrintStream

Tags: java, string, escaping

I want to print some strings in previous lines of java.io.PrintStream which means I want to change String in a specific line after I printed some lines in java.io.PrintStream.

Assume that, these are the lines I printed first

> A for Apple
>   B for Banana
>   C for Cat
>   D for Donkey

Now, I want to change the line (**B for Banana**) to (**B for Bag**)

I want PrintStream like this

> A for Apple
>   **B for Bag**
>
>   C for Cat
>   D for Donkey

I tried this.

```
out.print("\rB for Banana");
```

I know, we can only use **"\r" carriage return** for print the String in the same line. But I want to print my String in the previous line.
Is there any way to achieve my requirement in java?

Comment: Place the lines into a String array and manipulate whichever element you like.

Comment: You would have to print a few empty lines so that the previous output is invisible, then print 4 new lines.

Comment: What if lines are already printed?

Comment: I want to change the content in printed line (Previous line). Is that possible?
Sorry for the late replay. Thanks for the help.